# Changing H2 database admin user & password within Grails

Tags: grails, h2

Working with Grails 2.3.3 I want to change the sa password for my H2 db or possibly replace sa with a different username with the same admin rights.

If I change the sa password in the dbconsole using the setpassword command and then update the password in the datasource.groovy file is that all I need to do? Or are there other configuration files in the Grails environment I need to update?

I tried to improve security by creating a new user with admin rights in the dbconsole. I then changed the username and password in the DataSource.groovy file. But the application failed to come up and I got an error 'Unable to create initial connections pool - wrong username or password' presumably the sa user is setup elsewhere in the environment. It would be useful to get know where all the db login values are defined?

Answer (score 0):

`DataSource.groovy` is the only place that Grails looks for database connection info. A plugin or a custom DataSource/connection pool could be configured outside of there, but Grails itself only looks there.

Are you using a file-based H2 database, or starting it outside of Grails as a standalone server? In those cases it should be sufficient to make the change in the database and the corresponding changes in `DataSource.groovy`. If you're using the in-memory database, your user extra user will be lost when you restart the app.

Comment: It is a file based H2 dB within Grails. - when  I stop my app in the GGTS the dB server stops as well. All the dB changes I made to the users whilst it was running - that is changing the sa pwd and adding a new user with admin rights were reset when I restarted the app in GGTS. My aim is to get this working online via a war file. So I want to be able to make it more secure - perhaps I need to configure the H2 db to run independently from Grails in order to improve the password security - perhaps you can guide me to some documentation? Happy to use a file-based H2 system at this stage.

Comment: I want to move my grails app, which uses an in-memory/embedded H2 dB application, from a local development to onl;ineproduction. Trying to keep this simple I was expecting to simply create a app.war file and place it in a tomcat environment. Will the 'in-memory' H2 dB be part of that - or do I need to reconfigure so that a separate db is running as a stand-alone H2 server? If it will work 'in-memory' is there a way to reset the sa password or is the 'in-memory' passwords fixed to be blank?